# How do I add a simple search and replace to this loop in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I wrote this so far, it runs through and does exactly what I want, now I'm stuck. I can't seem to get it to open the newly created $NOSPACE.shtml and replace a word with the variable $SPACE though. A little help please?

```
$CITYLIST=import-csv CityList.txt
$CITYLIST | FOREACH-OBJECT { $_ }
FOREACH ($Item in $CITYLIST) { 
$Item.City
$NOSPACE=$Item.City.replace(" ","_")
$SPACE=$Item.City
Add-Content _citylist.shtml "`n<a class=`"cityareaslist`" href=`"`/$NOSPACE.shtml`">    $SPACE<`/a>" ; Copy-Item index.shtml "$NOSPACE.shtml"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(Get-Content "$NOSPACE.shtml") | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace 'word',$SPACE} | 
Set-Content "$NOSPACE.shtml"
```